# Pull a remote master to a non-forked repo's branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a **non-forked** repo that I have a branch where I want to pull a remote's master into that branch.

My repo consists of 2 branches, *master* and a *gh-pages*. *gh-pages* branch is where I want the remote's *master* to end up in.

- EDIT: I also want **my** *master* to be protected from accidentally pulling from the remote's master. Everything from the remote should **only** end up in *gh-pages*.

I'm bad at explaining stuff so I drew a picture too:

[image]

Comment: Is `My repo` a local repo on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an upstream remote to the github repo

```
git remote add upstream https://github...
```

Grab upstream branches (i.e. master)

```
git fetch upstream
```

Then set up gh-pages branch to track upstream/master

```
git branch -u upstream/master gh-pages
```

Then checkout gh-pages and merge

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge upstream/master gh-pages
```

If you go back to your local master branch and type `git pull` you should get an error like:

```
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

So your local `master` is "protected"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna play around with it a bit more, but it seems so far it's working.